# Weblogic logs

Tags: weblogic, java

Добрый день! Есть веблоджик, на котором крутится приложение/вебсервис. В коде логирование происходит таким образом

```
 private static final Logger logger = weblogic.logging.LoggingHelper.getServerLogger();
```

Собственно где посмотреть этот код?

Comment: @ttt Вы имели в виду лог?

Answer (score 1):

Код ничего не даст. Увидите [пустышку типа](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.fabric3.weblogic/fabric3-weblogic-mock/2.0.1/weblogic/logging/LoggingHelper.java)

Дело в том, что логгер веблоджика использует присоединяемое логгирование, в настройках можно приаттачить к нему или Apache Commons или Java или Log4J логгирование.

[Например так](http://janeonit.blogspot.ru/2012/10/commons-logging-api-and-weblogic-logging.html)